# Perl calls using system abruptly start failing

Tags: windows, perl, spawn

This week one of my standard perl [Strawberry perl 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread] scripts started failing. I tracked it down to a failing backtick operation.

Investigation showed that all the system-type calls, backtick, qx, pipe open, are failing. I tried building a debug version of perl, and even that fails, as the build process uses miniperl, which has the same problem.

> ..\miniperl.exe -I..\lib ..\make_ext.pl "MAKE=nmake -nologo" --dir=..\cpan --dir=..\dist --dir=..\ext --nonxs
> Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at ..\make_ext.pl line 580.
> Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at ..\make_ext.pl line 582.
> Unsuccessful make(dist/if): code=65280 at ..\make_ext.pl line 584.

I tried defining PERL5SHELL (full path to cmd, pwsh in place of cmd), turning off malware protection, everything I could think of reverting.

So, the actual question:
Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can track this down? It was working on Thursday, and there have been no system updates since then [OS version 10.0.22000].

Comment: It stands to reason that there must've been some changes to something, no?  You say "_one of my ... scripts_"  -- are others working? What happened with that one? With libraries for it? (With data that that one uses?)

Comment: My script was just the trigger for the investigation. The same behavior is present for the simplest spawn:

This is what I get on a different computer:
`> perl -e 'print qx(date /T);'
Sat 06/04/2022
`
On this one I get:
`> perl -e 'print qx(date /T)';
>`
plus a zero length file named 'date'.

Comment: Note there are two cmd, one that's seen by 32-bit apps, one seen by 64-bit apps. No idea if that's relevant.

Comment: *"I tried building a debug version of perl"* How did you do that?

Comment: Downloaded the source from GitHub, https://github.com/Perl/perl5; read the README.win32; edited win32/Makefile to use my local cpp (MSVC142) and to have CFG set to Debug [maybe should have been DebugFull); ran nmake on the Makefile; worked until it ran miniperl.

Comment: TechNet's Process Monitor may be able to shed some light on what the process actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Malwarebytes beta (4.5.10.200) version fixes this problem for me.

Comment: The beta version is now released as the official 4.5.10.200 component package 1.0.1702 yesterday (6/15).  I verified it works on all 4 of my PCs.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem starting a couple of weeks ago.  I use ActiveState perl, so I tried installing Strawberry perl, but got the same problem w/ Strawberry.  I also saw the zero length files getting created.  This is happening on multiple machines.  One is Winver 1909 and the other is 21H2.
A workaround is to use the full path for the program you want to run.
You can also insert the full path to cmd.exe ahead of the program.  Try this:

```
$temp = `$ENV{COMSPEC} /c date /T`;
print "\$temp = $temp";
```

I've been assuming this was due to a W10 security update, but I really do not know the cause.  I am going to write a sub called `Backticks()` that I could use like this:

```
print Backticks('date /T');
```

sub `Backticks` would return `$ENV{COMSPEC} /c @_`.
This is a hack, but at this point I do not know what else to do.

Comment: Thanks! This works! 

It was my assumption that it was some security update as well, but I couldn't find anything that looked promising. I also thought that setting PERL5SHELL to the full path would do the same thing, but apparently, no.

`Using command '$ENV{COMSPEC} /c date /T' => C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c date /T
Backticks: Sun 06/05/2022
====
qx:  Sun 06/05/2022`

Comment: Requiring the full path to `cmd` seems to indicate a problem with one's PATH. Can you provide the output of `perl -E"say $ENV{PATH}"`?

Comment: I had not changed the PATH when my Perl backticks stopped working.  There is nothing wrong with the PATH.  It is too long to show here.

Comment: I think I got it.  Just do this:

    `set PERL5SHELL=c:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c`

You can do this in a login.bat file.  You cannot use %COMSPEC% since \ must be escaped.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I tried setting PERL5SHELL earlier, but between forward and backward slashes, double slashes, single/double quotes, etc. I must have not gotten it quite right.

Thanks! Now I can proceed without having to alter existing scripts. I have reported this to the PERL bug list. Would you like to resubmit this as a proposed solution so that I can mark it as the best?

Comment: On further checking, I see that this does not fix everything.  Spurious files are still getting created.  E.g., zero-length file msg is created when I run `system ("msg * /time:86400 Greetings #1");` even though I do see the popup message.  Moreover, if I replace msg by msg.exe it does not work at all.

Comment: The system calls require the full path to the executable. You would need C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\msg.exe

Comment: Re "*It is too long to show here*",  Does it include `c:\WINDOWS\system32`?

Comment: Yes, path includes `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem starting about 10 days ago. I thought it had to do with path, but it appears ok. Problem is on 2 machines: Win10 and Win11. The Win11 PC I just purchased a couple of days ago, install strawberry and tested. Same error when I call system(..).
Short term solution I found is to **copy cmd.exe from c:\windows\system32 into the directory where the script is running**. Not a good solution, but it gets me through the day. I suspect it's some security update made in windows in the past couple of weeks.

Update 6/15/22: I can confirm that Malwarebytes beta (4.5.10.200) version fixes this. However, I had this problem on my Win11 PC before installing Malwarebytes. Maybe it's a problem with Windows Security?